# Retrieve only left, right, propertyName from the javers Change class

Tags: javers

I am using the following code to retreive the changes made to a version in my API response

```
List<Change> versionChanges = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build()).groupByCommit()get(0).get()
```

It gave me the following
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10185101/122550135-f3223b00-d050-11eb-9cc8-72982808cd2e.png

But I don't want this entire data to go as my API response
I just want to isolate `left`, `right`, `propertyName` in my response

I am not able to find an API on `Change.class` that can do me so ..

How can I achieve this

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<ChangesByCommit> changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build()).groupByCommit();
ValueChange valueChange = (ValueChange)changes.get(0).get().get(0);
String property = valueChange.getPropertyName();
Object originalValue = valueChange.getLeft();
Object newValue = valueChange.getRight();
```